# Looping counter - shortest method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, counter

So I'm trying to make code where every time a button is pressed an integer will increase until it reached its maximum value then it will go back (loop) to zero.

I'm trying to find out the shortest method to do this.

Let's say, for the sake of example, that the counter should go from 0 to 6 and then back to 0.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
count ++;
count *= (count != 7);
```

Can anyone come up with a better method?

***Note: Also, this was the 140,000th question with the tag "Objective-C" I think that's pretty cool.**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use modulo:

```
count = (count + 1) % 7
```

Comment: I won't! (There's a minimum time limit before I can accept answers!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like something like:

```
count = count < 6 ? ++count : 0;
```

But to be honest, I would prefer the old

```
if(count<6){
    count++;
}
else{
    count = 0;
}
```

Only for its readability, you see this, and your brain doesn't have to process much.

Comment: Can you check your code again, this didn't work... and I'm not familiar with this notation (although I do know that it IS a notation because I have seen it used before) (p.s. I wasn't the one who down voted)

Comment: I'll +1 to even it out, because this too is a good approach! Modulo is still my favorite though!

Comment: Thank you, I have set the max value to 6

Comment: What if count where set somewhere else to 8? If its a signed int (or something alike) it will lead to undefined behavior once it reaches its max + 1. Thats exactly why there is modulo. (Oh and modulo is much easier to read)

Comment: Oh and one more reason to use modulo. Consider stepping not 1 but 2, and wrapping at 7 not 6, in your case that would be: `count < 7 ? count + 2 : 0`. This will result in 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ooooops. With modulo ( `(count + 2) % 8` ) it would be 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, correct.

Comment: yeah, but that's not the case, also, I wouldn't use (count + 2) % 8 , since I think it hurts readability, maybe if I were code golfing, but not in production code,

Comment: how does using modulo hurt readability?? its a standard operator supported in most programming languages.

Comment: Yes, but imagine yourself skimming trough code you are not familiar with, to be honest, if I found my answer, or your answer I would have to stop, and think, actually when I was reading the question, I had to think about this: count *= (count != 7); "ok, so, false is 0 in Objective C, and he is multiplying and assigning it to count..."